# Last unit does not have enough valid bits

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm trying to deserialize a SecretKey at 256 bytes I've converted into a big integer then serialized into a txt file which looks this "22969273808780529062174833620303058617357675423823001978700975369013049788648" and then deserialize the key and convert it back into a secret key, but it gives me the error "The last unit does not have enough valid bits" where I try to convert the string into a `byte[]`

I'm using java 8 and using the `java.crpyto` import to try to do this.

```java
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileKey)); //läser nyckelfilen
    secretKey = reader.readLine(); //Lägger datan in i strängen

    reader.close();
}
catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] KeyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey); //gör om nyckeln till bytes

SecretKey KS = new SecretKeySpec(KeyData, 0, KeyData.length, "Blowfish"); // gör nyckeln till en secretkey
```

Comment: (1) a Blowfish key is not an integer and should not be treated as an integer (unlike some _asymmetric_ keys that are integers or partly so) (2) that value is obviously decimal and could be the result of `BigInteger.toString()` and is the correct size for 256 _bits_ (not bytes); it is NOT base64 so trying to decode it from base64 is total nonsense and doesn't work. You need to choose your serialization and then implement _matching_ deserialization.

Comment: Thanks, i used binary serialization and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your input string is not valid base64 encoded string.

Let me to demonstrate the root of the issue by decoding **'Hello'** string from **base64**:

**Base64**:

```
'Hello'
    | ASCII     | Base64(A=0, Z=25, z=51, /=63)
'H' | 0100 1000 | 00 000111
'e' | 0110 0101 | 00 011110
'l' | 0110 1100 | 00 100101
'l' | 0110 1100 | 00 100101
'o' | 0110 1111 | 00 101000
```

**Decode**:

- Map base64 text into bytes using `[A-Za-z0-9+/]` alphabet
- Ignore 2 first zero bits and collect bytes from binary stream

```
'H' 00 0001 11
'e' 00 01 1110
'l' 00 1001 01
'l' 00 10 0101
'o' 00 1010 00 

 0001 1101 0x1D
 1110 1001 0xE9
 0110 0101 0x65
 1010 00?? 0xA? <- Issue (Last unit does not have enough valid bits)
```